# How to make breqn work across multiple pages?

Tags: page-breaking, breqn

I'm creating a document programmatic and use [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) to automatically break equations across multiple lines. But when a single equation is larger then a page it fails.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)} = 
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(10)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}+
{RtMinLimitDev5minQty}_{ao, cmsid, gpid, mp, mpid, sl, M(5)}
\end{dmath}       
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Note that it is best to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. That is, exclude packages that are not necessary to reproduce the issue at hand (like `graphicx`, `lastpage`, `longtable`, ...).

Comment: Let me also express my welcome to TeX.sx. I've taken the liberty of  inserting line breaks in your big math expression to make the code (marginally) more readable for humans. That said, it might be helpful if you posted a real example of where your equation(s) exceed one full page than the sample code you provide.

Comment: @ben I would split the equation, a=page1eq, b=pag2eq, c=a+b, meaning I wouldn't look at TeX, but rather at the equation. Is this something that Mathematica vomited out?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides The equation in the example is not the actual equation which is causing the problem, just an example. The equations i'm trying to print come from power system analysis. I'm trying to avoid hand crafting or hard coding special cases for certain equations.

Comment: @ben Come on! There is no math or an engineering topic where you cannot simplify an equation. What happened to beautiful maths?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty

Comment: The nature of the MWE is such that it really should be modified before anyone will consider it. I'm therefore calling 'too localized'.